# What font was used in this image please?

Tags: font-identification

I would really appreciate help identifying the font used in this image please?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a pretty low-res image, but it looks like Helvetica Neue.

Comment: Wow, you are right. I should have looked closer. Thanks.

Comment: Probably Helvetica Neue over Helvetica due to the presence of that Ultra Thin weight in there.